# Missing option to select West-Europe for Windows Azure Websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

On windows-azure I have two subscriptions. On one subscribtion I have the option to select the data-center in West-Europe and on the other this option is missing, and only North-Europe is available. I want to deploy a windows-azure website in West-Europe. Any having this problem? what is the solution?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a capacity planning issue. See:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-us/9689188e-f875-44a4-b897-58abf5057c5a/why-is-west-europe-not-available-in-one-of-my-subscriptions

Presumably, it's available on your older subscription but not on the newer one.